# haml class/id syntax issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I wish to compute both the class and id of a  element, so I constructed a helper method, cell_class(row,col), so that cell_class(2,3) produces

```
class='cell .center_right', id='cell_23'
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how can I write this in haml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to rewrite your method to return a hash instead of a string, and then you can use the method in the attributes hash of your element in the Haml source:

```ruby
def cell_class
  #compute the values as needed
  {:class => 'cell center_right', :id => 'cell_23'}
end
```

then in the Haml:

```haml
%div{cell_class}
```

produces:

```html
<div class='cell center_right' id='cell_23'></div>
```

Note that Haml syntax deviates from Ruby syntax here – `{cell_class}` isn’t a valid Ruby hash, but you can use it in Haml.

The contents of the hash that you return from your method will be merged into any other attributes you specify in your Haml:

```haml
.another_class{cell_class}
```

produces:

```html
<div class='another_class cell center_right' id='cell_23'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this, I'd probably make the helper responsible for generating the element, like:

```
# in app/helpers/some_helper.rb
module SomeHelper
  def some_tag(object, &block)
    haml_tag('td', class: 'cell center_right', id: 'cell_23') {
      yield
    }
  end
end

# in app/views/some/view.html.haml
- some_tag(object) do
  ...content inside tag...
```

Alternately, you could have one helper return the class, and another return the ID, like:

```
%td{ class: cell_class_helper(object), id: cell_id_helper(object) }
  content
```

Better yet -- and the first thing I'd try -- you could re-structure your CSS to take advantage of HAML's [object reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#object_reference_) feature, letting you write:

```
%td[object]
  content
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out to be easy, once I got the syntax correct:

```
%div {class: #{cell_class(row, col)}", id: #{cell_id(row, col)}")
```

with row=2, cell=5, I get:

```
<div class='center_center' id='cell_25'>

</div>
```

just what I wanted.

The lesson to me is to avoid confusing sass notation ( ".cell .center_center") and haml shortcuts (".cell"), and rely on the nice ruby hash notation that haml provides.